# ASP.NET, Webforms how to get url id=?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

So I have a ASP.NET Webforms application in Visual Studio 2012. The home page of the application displays a table linked to a data base. One of the table rows link to a new page ViewProduct.aspx?id=X. The X will be the product id or product index within the database.

I would like to use this ID in the ViewProduct.aspx page to create a new table that displays data of the product corresponding to the url?id=X.

My issue is I have no clue how to turn the url Id into a variable? Can we do this within the pageload{ } and if so how? Can this only be done within the aspx code? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in you `ViewProduct.aspx.cs` file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        var productID = Request.QueryString["id"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not understand this but now I do! Example if my page was url?product=X I would do ["product"] etc. Thanks so much!

Comment: @702cs Yes that it correct. You can also use index values (i.e. `Request.QueryString[0]`) but the string name is the perferred method as it is more readable. You can also set a default value if the querystring value is null and doesn't exist (i.e `var productID = Request.QueryString["id"] ?? 0;`)

Comment: Thanks for the extra info!